# How to add element in array if it was found?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I use this method to find object in array:

```
lat arr = [];
found = this.obj[objKey].filter(item => item[internKeyName] == 7047);
arr.push(found);
```

Problem is that if element was not found it added this as `undefined` to array `arr`. How avoid this?

Why it does not find element with key: "subjectId":

```
let objKey = 7047;
let k = "subjectId";
let v = 7047;

found = this.obj[objKey].filter(item => item[k] == v);

console.log(found);// undefined
```

[image]

Comment: what is filter supposed to do? where is `internKeyName` defined, and why is the value hardcoded?

Comment: I hope you've found a correct answer, but honestly please be aware that we need a complete example for code questions. The example must actually be runnable where possible, and actively demonstrate the issue that you're having.

Comment: what does not work with the actual code? have you checked, that you got an array for filtering?

Comment: I use wrong function instead find I use filter it is mistake

Comment: `filter` might be usefull for more than one object fo find by the given condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `filter` won't return `undefined`, will return an empty array instead **(if none elements met the condition)**.

> Problem is that if **element** was not found it added this as `undefined` to array `arr`.

You probably want to find a specific element, so, I recommend you to use the function `find` if you want only one object rather than an Array with only one index.

```
lat arr = [];
found = this.obj[objKey].find(item => item[internKeyName] == 7047);
if (found) arr.push(found);
```

Comment: @dooglu can you either post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least more information about the context `this`?  I mean, more code basically.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid this by checking the length `found` before you push it to the array.

```
lat arr = [];
found = this.obj[objKey].filter(item => item[internKeyName] == 7047);
found.length > 0 && arr.push(...found);
```

I am using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to push each element as its own item to the new array, which I assume that is what you want. You can remove the `...` if you want all of the found items to be its own array item.

Comment: `found` is always `true`.

Comment: Oops I saw that is `x.find`

Comment: Why do you use `...found`?

Comment: It is called Spread Syntax, it basically takes an array and passes them as individual parameters. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 2):

You could push a spreaded array with the wanted objects directly, empty arrays are not spreaded ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)).

```
arr.push(...this.obj[objKey].filter(item => item[internKeyName] == 7047));
```